# How to get source code from google code using Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, repository, google-code, svn-checkout

Here is the project:
https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/checkout

I tried:

Folder > Right click > SVN Checkout > https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/

but doesn't work. This path doesn't look like others I have seen where it ends with /svn/trunk.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider typing a *command* starting with `svn`  ? And according to https://code.google.com/p/openpdn/source/checkout they are using Mercurial (`hg`) not subversion ! So you need to install Mercurial and type a command starting with `hg` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Mercurial repo, not an SVN repo. You'll need to use [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), not TortoiseSVN.

Comment: So there is no way to get the code using svn? I thought google code provides uniform access to code.

Comment: No, you need Mercurial, not Subversion... But both are free software, and you should be able to find these tools quickly.

Comment: @JoanVenge Google supports Git, Mecurial, and SVN repos, but they aren't interchangeable.  You need to use the appropriate tool for the repo type.

Comment: Ok thanks. Since I haven't used google code before I just assumed google uses the same repo type. I understand it now.